# Mouseover event fails to execute

Tags: html, css

I wan to add a mouse over event to a shape in HTML code
I declare the CSS code as below :

```
.tooltip {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000; outline: none;
  cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip span {
  margin-left: -999em;
  position: absolute;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
  border-radius: 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 2em; z-index: 99;
  margin-left: 0; width: 250px;
}
.tooltip:hover img {
  border: 0; margin: -10px 0 0 -55px;
  float: left; position: absolute;
}
.tooltip:hover em {
  font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;
  display: block; padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
}
.classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
.custom { padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em; }
* html a:hover { background: transparent; }
.classic {background: #FFFFAA; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; }
.critical { background: #FFCCAA; border: 1px solid #FF3334; }
.help { background: #9FDAEE; border: 1px solid #2BB0D7; }
.info { background: #9FDAEE; border: 1px solid #2BB0D7; }
.warning { background: #FFFFAA; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; }
```

I can run the mouse over event in this way

```
<a class="tooltip" href="#"> ADD HERE 
  <span class="custom info"><img src="Info.png" alt="Information" height="50" width="50" />
    <em>Information</em>
    1-July-2011<br />
    Value: 255<br />
    Type=Startup<br />
    QA<br />
    QA
  </span>
</a>
```

But it doesn't work this way, how can I fix it??

```
<a class="tooltip" href="#">
  <area shape="circle" coords="105,420,8" href="255.htm" /> 
  <span class="custom info">  
    <img src="Info.png" alt="Information" height="50" width="50" />
    <em>Information</em>
    1-July-2011<br />
    Value: 255<br />
    Type=Startup<br />
    QA<br />
    QA
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please add some line breaks to your HTML code, so it's better to read.

Comment: It might also help if you explain what exactly you are trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be that `<area>` element doesn't affect the flow and doesn't have proportions. What it means is that your tooltip that has no text (in your example) isn't even hoverable, because it has no dimensions (since there is no content in it).

http://jsfiddle.net/g8wYS/ – you can see that after I added the text the tooltip started to appear. You need to give your .tooltip link dimensions so it would be hoverable.

**UPD**. Also, `<area>` needs to be nested in `<map>` element, and `<map>` needs to be associated with an element, such as `<img>` or `<object>`. So using `<area>` alone doesn't really make sense. You can't really associate `<area>` with just any HTML element on the page. You can read about image map elements here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects#h-13.6.1

**UPD**. If I understand your objective right, you want a circle that would be hoverable and would trigger the tooltip to appear. Unfortunately, CSS `:hover` approach won't work with `<area>` element, as you can't nest other elements in it. So you can't do something like:

```
area:hover .tooltip { display:block }
```

So, if you want truly round object to be hoverable, you need to use SVG (and VML for IE < 9), it might be also possible with canvas, but I am not 100% sure. For that, you can use one of the libraries that simplify the use of SVG and allow to create it with JavaScript – such as http://raphaeljs.com/ – you would be able to do something like this with that library:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

circle.hover(function (event) {
    // position tooltip from the event objects mouse coordinates
}, function (event) {
    // hide tooltip
}, overScope, outScope);
```

However, to me it seems that you could just use a box, since it might be a big overhead to load an additional library only to add one hover effect. Also, you could write SVG and VML by hand right into your code, but I won't go into depth on this one, you would need to google that yourself (hint: SVG wouldn't be too hard and it will work right away in all modern browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE9 and up, and it can be styled with CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS, it's very easy to do that with the JS, especially with the jQuery

Comment: to do the required hover action